# Orthogonality of the wavefunctions on an subinterval?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, normalization

Lets say that functions (eigenfunctions) $\psi_0$ and $\psi_1$ are orthogonal on an interval $-d/2 < x < d/2$. Are they also orthogonal on any subinterval inside the interval $-d/2 < x < d/2$? For example if I take subinterval $$d/4 < x < d/2$$ Can I state that:
$$
\int\limits_{d/4}^{d/2}\overline{\psi}_0\psi_1\, dx=  0
$$
This would easier a lot of integrations for me...

Comment: In general this is most certainly not true.

Comment: Here is a mathematically precise analogy which should hopefully make it obvious that the answer is no: If you take two vectors which are orthogonal in ordinary 3d space and project them onto a plane, are the resulting projections necessarily orthogonal to each other?

Comment: Tha anwser is no. Oh well plenty integration here i come :)

Comment: As stated above, the answer is indeed no. But there's other tricks that might reduce the amount of integration you need to do. A good one to always look for is the integral of an odd function over a symmetric interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, orthogonal wavefunctions are in general not orthogonal on every subinterval. This is only true when the *support* of the wavefunctions (the regions in which they are nonzero) don't overlap. Energy eigenstates, for example, generally have overlapping support and are only orthogonal on whatever full interval they're defined on.

To see why wavefunctions with overlapping support are not orthogonal on every subinterval, consider the region of overlap. Both wavefunctions are nonzero everywhere in the region (by definition), which means they are both nonzero *somewhere* in the region. I choose my integration interval to be just that point, and I get a nonzero value.